# Automator command line: "Unable to open workflow"

Tags: automator

I created a workflow in Automator consisting of a single action, "Convert Format of Word Documents" (provided by Microsoft Word). I saved this in `~/Documents/convert_word_to_pdf.app`. I can run it by dragging a word file over this app, and it will generate a PDF for me. However, I can't figure out how to run it through the command line. I tried running `automator convert_word_to_pdf.app foo.docx` and I get `Unable to open workflow.`. I also tried `convert_word_to_pdf` and `convert_word_to_pdf/document.wflow` as arguments to `automator`, with the same results. What am I missing here?

Comment: And `~/Documents/convert_word_to_pdf.app foo.docx` ?

Comment: That didn't work either :(

Comment: And what's the error ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `-i`:

```
automator -i foo.docx ~/Documents/convert_word_to_pdf.app
```

Or if there are multiple arguments:

```
printf %s\\n foo.docx bar.docx|automator -i - ~/Documents/convert_word_to_pdf.app
```

See the man page:

```
SYNOPSIS
     automator [-v] [-i input] [-D name=value ...] workflow

DESCRIPTION
     automator runs the specified workflow.  To create or edit a workflow, use
     the Automator application.

     The following options are available:

     -D name=value
              Set variable name to value for this run of workflow.

     -i input
              Set input as the input to workflow If input is - then the con-
              tents of standard input is used.  The newline character (\n) is
              the delimiter for multiple strings.

     -v       Run in verbose mode.
```

Answer (score 0):

Bundles on OSX are just directories, so to run a program You have to call executable. It'll look like:

`~/Documents/convert_word_to_pdf.app/Contents/MacOS/Application\ Stub path/to/foo.docx`